# How to create in app purchase for a courses app. Each course has different prices and after purchase a user has lifetime access to the course

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am new to mobile development and I have stuck in app purchases. All in-app-purchases information on the internet are based on the subscription or single non-consumable product. I believe each course should be non-consumable product. But if I have 150 courses, isn't it tedious to create 150 in-app-purchase id for each courses.

Do we have to create in-app-purchase (product id) inside appstoreconnect for each course? or is it possible to create single in-app-purchase (called courses id) to make purchases for the different priced courses?

My question is different from the nonConsumable in-app-purchase questions in StackOverflow.

Thank you!

Comment: You will probably need to create a "credits" type system where the user can purchase consumable "credits" and then redeem a variable number of credits for courses.

Comment: One way to do it is to make sure that the prices are in a multiple of X..for example 5. Then you can create IAP products on AppStore like this.. $5, $10, $15 .... $100. We have been using the similar mechanism in most of our app.